# iam creating login page with sql connection bt error will occur {dr}value type cant be converted

Tags: .net, sql, c#-4.0

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Shared dr As SqlDataReader
'Shared da As SqlDataAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection("Data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog= icare; Integrated security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from userlogin where UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con)
    SqlDataReader(dr)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        TextBox1.Text = dr("user Name").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Password").ToString
        'If (TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.Text) Then
        '    Response.Redirect("Defaulft.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Home.master")
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = "Invalid USERNAME & PASSWORD"
    End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be not complete (truncated may be?) - Anyway, I suggest you perform a step-by-step trace (F5). If you can connect to the database, determine the offending statement. It is not clear from your pose which line fails.

Your code:

SqlDataReader(dr)

is ambigious to me.

Check: [MSDN-Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx) for a clear example similar to your case.